# Regex For css SelectorText

Tags: css, regex

I'm trying to write a `regex` to extract nodes ids and classes from `css` `selectorText`.

For example:

```
.linear *, .test-in *, .test-out *, .test *, .test-in-out.casanova#casanova * > #test22
```

I need a `regex` to extract only the classes and ids:

```
linear , test-in , test-out , test , test-in-out , casanova , casanova , test22
```

so I need a `regex` to match any string that starts with `./#` and ends with `space/./#` the first occurrence for any of them.

I manage to create [this](https://regex101.com/r/Z7tTub/2):

```
(?:^|[\.]).*?([^\s]+(?!\.))
```

but as you can see it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:\.|\#)([_a-zA-Z0-9-\:]*)(?:\b|<|>|\+|~|\[)
```

This regex will also capture some invalid css selectors such as **-_--__abc**. But in your case I believe this will solve your problem.